# Замена фрагмента в onBackPress

Tags: android, backstack

Ситуация - есть splashFragment - страница, с которой можно перейти на авторизацию и регистрацию. Если юзер не авторизован, он видит её. Если авторизован - главную. ПРи запуске работает на ура.  onBackPressedd обрабатываю нажатие -

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            Log.i("bpress", getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container).getClass().getSimpleName());
            bpCount = 0;
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            Log.i("bpress", getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container).getClass().getSimpleName());
        }

        //Else, nothing in the direct fragment back stack
        else {
            // Let super handle the back press
            bpCount++;
            switch (bpCount) {
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Для выхода нажмите \"Назад\" ещё раз",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    super.onBackPressed();
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (User.isAuthorized) {
            Log.i("bpress", "auth " + User.isAuthorized);
            SplashFragment fragment = null;
            Log.i("bpress", getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container).getClass().getSimpleName());
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container) instanceof SplashFragment) {
                fragment = (SplashFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
            }
            if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {
                Log.i("bpress", "replace");

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new MainFragment(), MainFragment.class.getCanonicalName())
                        .commit();
            }
        }

//        If the fragment exists and has some back-stack entry
    }
```

То есть если юзер авторизован и мы видим этот splashFragment, то надо его заменить на главную страницу, но почему то и до и после popBackStack в лог мне выводится getClass().getName() класс фрагмента который был до нажатия на кнопку back, хотя я жду, что после выталкмвания фрагмента из стека он должен смениться на фрагмент, который лежит под ним. Каким образом можно добиться такого поведения7

Answer (score 1):

Когда добавляется `FragmentTransaction`, фрагменты на самом деле не меняются сразу. Когда транзакция отправлена системе, она уберет из контейнера старый фрагмент и добавит новый. Поэтому вывод текущего фрагмента сразу после отправки транзакции не имеет особого смысла.

Что насчёт самого фрагмента? Он появляется на экране?

Comment: Прошу прощения, что не отписался сразу, уже решил проблему. Переметил проверку в OnBackStateChangedListener.